# Error message "Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to create a recursive call to a method but receive error:

> Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack
>   overflow state

Just a bit of a background, I'm migrating a PowerBuilder app. to a C#.NET windows app., the PB app. has a timer that is done programmatically which will execute the main method at a specific time. The PB code runs on two machines, one timer is set at the '0' mark and on machine #2, it is set at the 30 second mark.

PB code below:

```
ue_wait event:

gi_offset = //Global variable set at the application open event, equivalent to program.cs - main event. Will be 0 or 30 depending on the machine.

li_difference = Integer( String( Now(), 'ss')) //Gets the seconds from the current date time.

DO UNTIL li_difference = gi_offset

 ls_status = 'current second: ' + String( Now(), 'ss') + ' starting on:' + String( gi_offset)// Builds a string to display in a static text control in PB, label in C#.

 IF st_status.Text <> ls_status THEN st_status.Text = ls_status

 Yield()

 li_difference = Integer( String( Now(), 'ss'))

LOOP

//execute main processing method.

ue_action().

//End of event

ue_action event
Do main processing.

Call ue_wait()
```

My C# code below:

```
private void Form1_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e)        
{            
    ue_wait();        
}

private void wf_actions_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{            
      //Should fire after all of the form has loaded.                            
      Shown += Form1_Shown;        
}  

private void ue_wait()        
{            
    long todays_date_in_seconds = DateTime.Now.Second;
    long ll_global_offset = 0;            
    string ls_status = "";                         

    todays_date_in_seconds = DateTime.Now.Second;            

    while (!(todays_date_in_seconds == ll_global_offset))   
    {                
        ls_status = "Current second: " + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + " starting on: " + ll_global_offset.ToString();                
        lbl_status.Text = ls_status;                
        todays_date_in_seconds = DateTime.Now.Second;            
    }             

    ue_action();  
}

private void ue_action()        
{            
//After the main processing is done, it goes back to ue_wait().            
    ue_wait();        
}
```

So I have tried the two possibilities that I found on the Inet:

```
this.Shown += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Shown);

this.Activated += AfterLoading;
```

However when calling ue_action I get the error below in the ue_wait event for  both...

> {Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack
>   overflow state.}

Fails on the first line: `long todays_date_in_seconds = DateTime.Now.Second;`

I found the .NET timer but it does not allow you to set the Start at a specific point in time, ie: seconds, `Timer.Start() = 0` mark or T`imer.Start() = 30` second mark (30000 milliseconds). The interval is one part that would work as I could set it to execute every 60 seconds.

After doing some googling, because there is 'recursive' programming, this is causing the 'Stack Overflow', how can I avoid the 'Stack Overflow' in the .NET environment or would there be another way to do what I need to do in the C#.NET environment?

Comment: I don't see any bailout or early returns for the `ue_action` and `ue_wait` methods. How would these two not call each other infinitely (thus leading to the stack overflow)?

Comment: `ue_action` calls `ue_wait` which calls `ue_action` which calls `ue_wait` which calls `ue_action` which calls `ue_wait` which calls `ue_action` which calls `ue_wait` which calls `ue_action` which calls `ue_wait` which calls `ue_action` which calls `ue_wait` which calls (you get the idea). Infinite loop is infinite loop in any language, nothing specific about .NET.

Comment: I understand that this is an infinite loop, that is how it is done in the PB app. the app runs 24/7 and continuously loops within itself to build the timer and process what it needs to process in the ue_action event and then continue back to the ue_wait, etc... There is Yield() function in the DO UNTIL loop "Yields control to other graphic objects, including objects that are not PowerBuilder objects. Yield checks the message queue and if there are messages in the queue, it pulls them from the queue.". Not sure if this function helps with the Stack Overflow, maybe something similar in .NET.

Comment: .NET has a [`Application.DoEvents`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx) method which will act similarly, but it is a completely wrong approach. I doubt you want to spin a single CPU core to 100% just to fire a single event each second. Using loops for timing is a bad idea in any language, you wouldn't even use it in a 8051 microcontroller if you can use a simple timer instead.

Comment: I agree with you, the PB app was written in 2004 but the dev tool does not have a timer control like .NET. I'm a PB developer myself and wrapping my brain around .NET. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to use a 1s `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, that's a no brainer:

```
// timer initialization, somewhere
timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer.Interval = 1000;
timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;

DateTime? _lastHandledTimestamp = null;
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get current timestamp
    var currentTimestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var currentSecond = currentTimestamp.Second;

    // not the correct second yet?
    if (currentSecond <= TARGET_SECOND)
        return;

    // truncate seconds and check if we already handled this hh:mm
    var flooredToNearestMinute = currentTimestamp.AddSeconds(-currentSecond);
    if (_lastHandledTimestamp.HasValue &&
        _lastHandledTimestamp.Value >= flooredToNearestMinute)
        return;

    // if we're here, we are good to go
    _lastHandledTimestamp = flooredToNearestMinute;
    DoStuff();
}
```

If you want to avoid triggering the tick event every second, use a `System.Threading.Timer` instead, and use its `Timer.Change` method to calculate the next time it needs to fire on each iteration.

Comment: I will try that, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Groo, thanks for the input on the timer, I tweaked it for what I need to do.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ls_status = "";
        var currentSecond = DateTime.Now.Second;

        ls_status = "Current second: " + currentSecond.ToString() + " starting on: " + Il_offset.ToString();

        lbl_status.Text = ls_status;

        if (currentSecond == Il_offset && Ib_processing_completed)
        {
            //Main processing method
            ue_action();
        }

    }
```

In the Tick event, I populate an instance variable of offset in the PageLoad, in this case it will be 1 or 31 and set a Boolean variable to true in the ue_action event after successful processing.

To get rid of the original problem, instead of doing recursive programming and looping, the Tick event was recommended instead which meets my needs.

Thank you, the .NET learning curve begins.

William.